# How to use auth in api routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.6, laravel-authorization

I'm trying to call `Auth::user()` in my `routes/api.php` file.

But the `Auth::user()` returns `null`.

Meanwhile, as in the `routes/web.php` file it work.

How to fix it?

I will be grateful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call with `guard()`

```
Auth::guard('api')->user();
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not work...
I found a solution - so good to use, wouldn't it be (appreciated)?
Thanks...

Comment: api are stateless but if you added web middleware, then it will behave like a web url i guess as web middleware uses a number of middleware class like cookies, csrf token, binding etc,

Comment: @ZeroOne that could be the case but its not clear though

Comment: Please, for a valid answer you must config propper api driver